# Angular JS: ng-switch on boolean not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-switch

I am trying to conditionally display a directive based on a boolean value stored in the parent scope. I can't figure out why the below does not work. By, "not work" I mean neither directives are displayed.

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" ng-switch="userIsAuthenticated">
    <account-item item="accountMenuItem" ng-repeat="accountMenuItem in anonymousMenuItems" ng-switch-when="false"></account-item>
    <account-item item="accountMenuItem" ng-repeat="accountMenuItem in authenticatedMenuItems" ng-switch-when="true"></account-item>
</ul>
```

Neither directives are shown even thought "userIsAuthenticated" is set to 'false' in my test case. If I add `{{userIsAuthenticated}}` above the  directives 'false' is output as expected.

I've also tried this:

```
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right" ng-switch={{userIsAuthenticated}}>
    <account-item item="accountMenuItem" ng-repeat="accountMenuItem in anonymousMenuItems" ng-switch-when={{false}}></account-item>
    <account-item item="accountMenuItem" ng-repeat="accountMenuItem in authenticatedMenuItems" ng-switch-when={{true}}></account-item>
</ul>
```

If I remove the conditional ng-switch-when attribute from either of the directives they will display. So I'm know the problem is my ng-switch.

Comment: Can you show what's in `account-item` directive?

Answer (score 2):

Your usage of ng-switch works in this simplified demo, of course without your `account-item` directive:
http://plnkr.co/AppN8xmFeIwjaP631lj7

Without seeing the code for `account-item`, it is hard to guess what might be interfering with it.  You might consider using `ng-if` to handle displaying one item or another.

```
<ul>
  <div ng-if="!userIsAuthenticated">Content when not authenticated</div>
  <div ng-if="userIsAuthenticated">Content when authenticated</div>
</ul>
```

Update
Also make sure you bind to an object property, instead of a primitive boolean.  Like: `user. authenticated`

Comment: I've added a (very simple) `ng-repeat` to these items in this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/cy8AfaBTlRwsEplHTBer?p=preview), seems to work ok. So indeed `account-item` should be the key here.

Answer (score 1):

Since `ngSwitchWhen` has a priority of 800, you need to set a higher priority to your custom directive (i.e. `account-item`) in order for it to be compiled before being process by the `ngSwitchWhen` directive. E.g.:

```
.directive('accountItem', function () {
    return {
        ...
        priority: 900,
        ...
    };
});
```